# Combining touching polygons

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, combine

### PROBLEM STATEMENT

I am trying, based on previous posts in this website, to combine polygons within the same layer but just when they touch each other by means of **pyQGIS**.

1. It doesn't work (proper errors are shown below)
2. I want also to create a layer with merged polygons at the end
3. I want to know the length of touching part

### SCRIPT TRIAL

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import processing
import itertools 
layer=QgsVectorlayer(r'C:\Users\...\buildings.shp',"buildings","ogr")
features = layer.getFeatures()
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.permutations(features,r=2):
    if geom1.geometry().touches(geom2.geometry()):
        geom1.combine(geom2)
```

Returned error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 3, in <module> AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'combine'
```

Comment: For starters, you should probably replace your last line with something like `union = geom1.geometry().combine(geom2)` (this is the cause of your error).

Comment: ok, thank you. Now, it doesn't return an error but I don't know if it has done anything; so how can I export these information to a layer?